# network trouble with hp bl465c g7 and rhel6.5

Tags: linux, redhat, hp

I have an HP BL465c g7 that worked fine with RHEL6.3. After upgrading to 6.5 the network stopped working. Can ping itself but no the gateway or anywhere else. IPtables are clear, eth-tool reports a link, but no auto-negotiation, SELinux is off, and I see nothing strange in the logs.

Has anyone experienced this before? What might the problem be?

Update:

ifcfg-eth0 is in good order. Dmesg info:

```
[root@gram1428 boot]# dmesg   |grep -i eth.
be2net 0000:04:00.0: eth0: Emulex OneConnect port 0
be2net 0000:04:00.1: eth1: Emulex OneConnect port 1
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
device eth0 left promiscuous mode
eth0: no IPv6 routers present
device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
device eth0 left promiscuous mode
```

Update 2

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2C:76:8A:AD:8A:A2
          inet addr:10.178.8.8  Bcast:10.178.11.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2e76:8aff:fead:8aa2/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:20823 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2018 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:85352 (83.3 KiB)
```

Looks like it might be this problem:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/667283

Comment: Your devices may have been renamed. Please post the output of `dmesg | grep -i eth`.

Comment: what about output of ifconfig or "ip link"?